# Inner Join AND Left Join in Same Query?? (mySQL)

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query selecting/showing the results I intended for; however, one of the columns is not in the format I want to display since I am selecting a code that only translates in the resulting chart if there is a join done from another table.

But, I already have a LEFT Join in my query, so when I try to do an additional join from a separate table, my query doesn't work. Would anyone know if it's possible/ how to keep my existing query but add an additional join.

---

Here is my current query and the results:

```
Select a.ye, a.AppsCreated, ((a.AppsCreated- b.AppsCreated)/b.AppsCreated) as "% Change" from(
select count(*) as "AppsCreated" , cycle_id as ye
from applications
group by cycle_id
)a 
left join
(
select cycle_id as ye, count(*) as "AppsCreated"
from applications
group by cycle_id
)b 
on a.ye -1 = b.ye
```

AND the result

| Ye | Apps Created | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | .00 |
| 2 | 4000 | .33 |
| 3 | 5000 | .25 |
| 4 | 3002 | .39 |
| 5 | 4005 | .33 |
| 6 | 3008 | .33 |

---

I am trying to join the "ye" (aka the cycle_id from the existing 'applications' table) with 'id' from a separate 'cycles' table)

In a separate query, I have it as (INNER JOIN cycles ON cycles.id = applications.cycle_id)

This would turn the "ye" row from 1, 2, 3, etc. to the physical year timeframe this matches with in the cycles table.

Sorry if this is all complicated, but if anyone knows how to keep my existing query but allow for the tables to join to display the corresponding ID values, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!!

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server please correct your tags. And please provide sample data, ideally as DDL+DML.

Comment: you should be able to just add as another inner join, make sure you point the table reference accordingly.
INNER JOIN cycles ON cycles.ye = b.ye

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.

Comment: Pls show how you tried to do the inner join and describe what went wrong with your attempt, not just simply saying that it did not work. An inner join on your derived table should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can phrase your query using `lag()`, assuming that you have a `cycle_id - 1` for all rows:

```
select cycle_id, count(*) as cnt,
       lag(count(*)) over (order by cycle_id) as prev_cnt,
       (-1 + (count(*) / lag(count(*)) over (order by cycle_id))) as ratio_change
from applications a
group by cycle_id;
```

(Note:  Even if there are gaps, you can still use window functions, but your sample data has no gaps.)

I'm guessing this will simplify the `join` as well.